# Architecture question about one Elasticsearch instance per microservice

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, microservices

I like the approach of microservices. Easily(or easier) to deploy, to manage, to develop and so on than a monolith. The microservices pattern says one database instance per microservice, in the most cases that isn't a matter but in some cases it is. I explain my problem with an example.

I have a web service where the users can upload e.g. an image and other users can comment and rate it and there's a view counter. Now I would implement 4 services.

1. Upload Image Service

   - the user uploads its image to the website
   - the image has some meta information like description, title, tags, upload date
2. Comment Service

   - if an user adds a comment to the image then this service handles the request and creates an entry in the database with the attributes content, videoId, userId and date
3. View Counter Service

   - always if an user views/clicks that image a new request to service will be created and an new entry in the DB with the user id and video id is stored

Each service has its own database and all services are completely independent to each other. The communication between services is only via REST API. The DB is ElasticSearch.

And here comes the problem. I will create a fourth service the "Image Search Service". It's a really common task like the search function in youtube.
For the best search results I need each of the attributes/information from the preceding 3 services. The search is depending on, of course, the tags, description and the upload date but the likes/dislike have an influence and views and comments too. An image with a high view count will be ranked higher, for example.

But when I store all this information in separate DBs then I can not consider it in one query, but I think this necessary by a full text search.

Has someone may be some experiences or some ideas to solve this problem or is there may be a best practice? I rode something about event sourcing but that's not the right solution for this special problem.

Of course I can create three requests to each service and then create an algorithm and merge the results by myself, but I think elasticsearch is the right man for this job.

Answer (score 0):

JHipster uses elasticsearch on top of a mysql DB. Maybe this could be a solution.